# How does overloading work?

Tags: oop, overloading

Let have these overloaded methods in a class:

```
    class Test{
        public void func1(int X , String s) {
             // do something
        }
        public void func1(int X) {
             // do something
        }
        public void func1(int X , int Y) {
             // do something
        }
```

what happen (what does the compiler do) when func1(2,3) from another class is called:

- the compiler finds directly the thired version of func1 in class Test like calling non-overloaded methods or
- like if-else statements, the entire overloaded methods with name func1 are tested to find which of them has the same set of arguments as func(2,3)

I searched in some documentations but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: I'm not too sure if I understand the question but.... What happens is the compiler checks for a method that is defined with the name you are calling ie func1.Then it goes through them to check if any of their signatures match the given parameters in the same order as you passed them in. If a match is found the method will be called... If not a Nosuchmethodexception will be thrown. So in a nutshell the method name as well as its signature defined by the parameters it is expecting makes it unique to the others with the same name.

Comment: compiler doesn't do anything when functions are called, as that is a runtime operation. Compiler compiles the code.

Comment: @Jacques: so, in this example, the compiler should check the signature of func1 three times to find the right one (func1(int , int)), isn't it?

Comment: @eis: yes, my mistake, so what happen in runtime in this case?

Comment: Same idea just replace the word compiler with virtual machine.. Etc